# Attempting to send POST request to API with JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to make an api get request using JS's built in XMLHttpRequest system. I am not sure why this function fails to work.

```
function updateStats(username){
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest;
  var url = "https://pitpanda.rocks/api/players/" + username;
  request.open("GET", url);
  request.send();
  request.onload = (e) => {
    return request.response;
  }
}
```

My code is running on CodePen right now https://codepen.io/casperqf/pen/NWXGeqa

Comment: `request.open("GET", url);` sends a GET, not a POST.

Comment: What "fails to work" about it?  Now is a good time to start using your browser's debugging tools.  Are there any errors on the console?  Is the AJAX request made at all?  What is the server's response?  Is the functino invoked at all?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] and indicate specifically what isn't working as expected.

Comment: `new XMLHttpRequest()` - but really you should be using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in 2022.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using `fetch`. Allows you to set the `method` and some other values.

Can do with fetch and not with XHR:
You can use the API with the request and response objects.
You can perform `no-cors` requests, getting a response from a server that doesn't implement CORS. You can't access the response body directly from JavaScript.

```js
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

function updateStats(username, stats){
  postData('https://pitpanda.rocks/api/players/' + username, { stats: stats })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data); // JSON data parsed by `data.json()` call
  });
}

updateStats('otik', 123);
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't usually helpful. Please give some context and explanation as to why this helps.